# Detrending using moving average

Tags: trend, moving-window

In Terrence C. Mills book Im currently reading [The Foundation of Modern Time Series Analysis](http://www.palgrave.com/us/book/9780230290181) on while discussing Person's detrending methods, he mentions the following result.

> ... Concider the deviation of $x_t$ from a three year moving average centered on $$x_t:x_t-(x_{t+1}+x_t+x_{t-1})/3$$.
>    This is equivalent to:
>   $$-\frac{1}{3}(x_{t+1}-2x_t+x_{t-1})=-\frac{1}{3}\Delta^2x_{t+1}$$
>
> so the correlation between the two series will be identical to the correlation between the deviations of the three-year moving averages...
>
> <sub>pages:41-42</sub>

Im not sure how the above equality is derived. How does this work mathematically?

Comment: I just want to make doubly sure: the thing you want demonstrated is that this $-\frac{1}{3}(x_{t+1}-2x_t+x_{t-1})$ equals this $-\frac{1}{3}\Delta^2x_{t+1}$? (I presume you know the definition of $\Delta$ being used there?)

Comment: @Glen_b yeah I want to see how this equality exists. I know $\Delta$ refers to the number of times the data was differenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta^2(x_{t+1})&=&\Delta(\Delta(x_{t+1}))\\
&=&\Delta(x_{t+1}-x_t)\\
&=&\Delta(x_{t+1})-\Delta(x_t)\qquad\text{(by linearity of }\Delta \text{ operator)}\\
&=&(x_{t+1}-x_t)-(x_{t}-x_{t-1})\\
&=&x_{t+1}-2x_{t}+x_{t-1}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Wow, a value centered by a moving average is just a second difference over the number of variables we wish to take the average of. Thanks!